# What is the best way to handle bearer token from external server/api

Tags: node.js, bearer-token, api-authorization

[image]

Hi, currently I'm new to node.js, I have received the token using routes app.post('/getToken'), then later i need the token to call from the external api to get some data and populate it on the front-end. What is the best way to handle the token that i received from the external api.

are there a better way to only call getToken just once, then i can freely get the data from external api by using the token as long the token is not expired and how should i verified the token ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bearer token from your request header like this

```
let bearerToken = req.headers.authorization;
```

After that you can pass this token to your external API